# Trying to implement example using HttpExchange

Tags: java, http, jetty

I'm trying to implement the code under "Asynchronous Exchanges" from this link in the jetty documentation:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/HttpClient#Asynchronous_Exchanges

```
HttpExchange exchange = new HttpExchange();

// Optionally set the HTTP method
exchange.setMethod("POST");

exchange.setAddress(new Address("ping.host.com", 80));
exchange.setURI("/ping");
// Or, equivalently, this:
exchange.setURL("http://ping.host.com/ping");

client.send(exchange);

System.out.println("Exchange sent");
```

I'm trying to figure out which HttpExchange class is being used. I downloaded jetty from here http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/

but couldn't find a reference to HttpExchange anywhere in the files. Could it be the HttpExchange from com.sun.net.httpserver? When I try to use the one from sun I get an error telling me that the class doesn't have an HttpExchange() constructor (with no params).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [`org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpExchange.html), assuming you're using the version from Eclipse.

Comment: Am I downloading it from the right spot? Or maybe I should install it through eclipse?

Comment: The class is in the jetty-client-xx.jar jar in the lib folder of the distro. Make sure that's included in your classpath.